# psexec trying to exec script error

Tags: powershell

I am learning how to interact with PowerShell and PsTools, and I have a problem with `psexec`.

I got a ps1 script named `test.ps1` and inside it I have `Get-Service` which gives me the all services in my computer. Now I am going into PowerShell and go to `c:\pstools`. Then I type

```
psexec.exe C:\test\test.ps1
```

and it fails and returns me this error:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application

What could be the problem?

Comment: the content of test.ps1 is

 'Get-Service'

Comment: The content of the script is incidental to the problem. It would help if you clarified the reason for using `psexec`, because your question otherwise sounds as if you simply want to execute a PS script locally, as the current user - in which case use of `psexec` is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

`PsExec` launches an executable.  You need to specify the executable for PowerShell and associated arguments:

```
psexec.exe -accepteula -nobanner -s -h -d powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoLogo -File "C:\test\test.ps1"
```

Comment: ++; worth mentioning that there's no good reason to use `psexec` unless you target one or more _remote_ machines (`psexec \\<host> ...`); I suspect the OP mistakenly thinks that `psexec` is _PowerShell_'s executable name.

Comment: @mklement0 That's not true.  It's also useful for running programs as the SYSTEM account.

Comment: That's good to know (and I've updated my answer accordingly). That said, as written, your answer uses that very feature (`-s`) without explanation, along with a number of other unexplained options, while not addressing the OP's pointless use of `psexec`, so I took the liberty of undoing my upvote.

Comment: @mklement0 People should be expected to be able to read documentation.  There's no reason to use psexec without one of three reasons: impersonation, remote connectivity, or SYSTEM-run tasks.

Comment: If you're assuming a familiarity with `psexec` and/or faith in users consulting the docs, the distraction-free answer is `psexec powershell -file C:\test\test.ps1`. Anything else - without explanation - is either a distraction or a potential source of confusion.
What's worse, your use of `-s` is unnecessary for the simple task of obtaining the list of running services and not stating _why_ you use it and how it changes the behavior of `psexec` causes further confusion.
The only reason I'm abstaining from a down-vote at this point is that the _prose_ part of your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The *immediate* answer to your question is:

- `psexec` requires a (binary) *executable* as its first argument and cannot execute *scripts* directly.
- Therefore, you must pass the Windows PowerShell executable name to `psexec` and in turn pass the desired script to the latter as an *argument*, via the `-File` parameter:

  ```
  psexec powershell -File C:\test\test.ps1
  ```
- That said, *this particular use of `psexec` is pointless*, as it would execute the script *locally*, as the current user, in which case use of `psexec` is a needless complication:

  - If you already know that, and the `psexec` command at hand is just a simplified example, never mind.
  - Otherwise, read on below.

---

- The `ps` in **`psexec` and [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) has nothing to with *PowerShell***; PsTools is a collection of CLIs for managing Windows machines *remotely*, including *processes*, a common abbreviation of which is "ps", inspired by the standard `ps` Unix utility, which in turn inspired the initial tool in the collection, `pslist`; the **primary purpose of [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) is to invoke arbitrary command lines on *remote* machines**<sup>[1]</sup>
  .
- To **invoke a PowerShell script *locally***:

  - **From *inside* PowerShell** itself, simply invoke the file path directly:

    - `PS> c:\test\test.ps1`
    - `PS> & "c:\test\test.ps1"`, if the file path is / must be quoted or is provided via a variable or expression.
  - **From *outside* of PowerShell, such as `cmd.exe` ("Command Prompt")** or `bash`, you must **invoke the PowerShell executable *explicitly*** and pass it the script file path via the `-File` parameter:

    - *Windows PowerShell*: `C:\> powershell -file c:\test\test.ps1`
    - PowerShell *Core*: `C:\> pwsh -file c:\test\test.ps1`
    - In other words: the **PowerShell's executable name** is

      - **`powershell.exe`** for *Windows PowerShell*,
      - vs. **`pwsh`** for the cross-platform *PowerShell Core* edition (with extension `.exe` on Windows).
- If you do need ***remote* execution**:

  - **Pass `\\`-prefixed machine name(s) or IP address(es) to `psexec`**; e.g., the following command executes the `hostname` utility on machine `somemachine`:
    `psexec \\somemachine hostname`
    There is *no* benefit to using `psexec` without targeting a *different* machine.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - However, `psexec` is normally not needed, because **PowerShell has *built-in* support for remoting** (i.e., the ability to execute commands on other machines; remoting requires setup, however - run [`Get-Help about_Remote_FAQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq) for more information); e.g., the equivalent of the above command is:
    `Invoke-Command -ComputerName somemachine { hostname }`

---

<sup>[1] As [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) points out, `psexec` can also be used for *local* execution as the *system account* (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, the account that represents the computer as a whole) with the `-s` option.

Additionally, you can also run locally as *another user*, using the `-u` parameter - which, however, the standard `runas` utility can do as well (the latter doesn't offer passing the target user's password as a *parameter* for security reasons, but does offer to securely *save* a password for later reuse).

Run `psexec -h` for help.</sup>